# Как правильно организовать проверку параметров, через instanceof ?

Tags: javascript

В методах принимающих параметры: weapon и target хочу сделать проверку на корректность параметра, через instanceof (если не выполняется то генерировать TypeError). Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно ее реализовать

```js
function Weapon(name, damage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
    this.getDamage = function () {
        return this.damage;
    };
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'toString', {
        value: function () {
            return name + 'damage: ' + this.getDamage() + " points";
        }
    });
}
var bow = new Weapon('Golden bow, ', 20);
var sword = new Weapon('Magic sword, ', 40);
var stick = new  Weapon('Wanderers Stick of Deserts', 5);
console.log(Object.keys(bow)); // check access to keys

function Unit(maxHealth, basicDamage, evasion, type) {

    this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    this.currentHeaalth = maxHealth;
    this.basicDamage = basicDamage;
    this.evasion = evasion;
    this.type = type;
    /*method for showing the status of life, true if the "health" is greater
     than 0 and false if equal to or lower */
    this.isAlive = function () {
        return this.currentHeaalth > 0
    };
    /* a method that
     shows the level of health*/
    this.getFormattedHealth = function () {
        return this.currentHeaalth + '/' + this.maxHealth + ' HP';
    };
    /* The method that defines the weapon created in the constructor "Weapon"*/
    this.setWeapon = function (weapon) {
        try {
            var me = this;
            me.weapon = weapon;
            return me;

        } catch (e) {
            if (weapon instanceof !Weapon) {
                console.log(TypeError);
            }
        }
    };
    /*a method that returns the base damage of the heroand damage to the
     weapon (if it is set)*/
    this.getDamage = function () {
         return (this.weapon ? this.weapon.getDamage() : 0) + this.basicDamage;
    };
    /* The method of hitting
     the hero for the chosen purpose*/
    this.kick = function (target) {
        try {
            if (this.isAlive()) {
                target.currentHeaalth = Math.max(0, target.currentHeaalth - this.getDamage());
            }
            return this;
        }catch (e) {
            if (target instanceof !Unit) {
                console.log(TypeError);
            }
        }

    };
    /*method for showing all the characteristics of the hero and changes
     with them*/
    this.toString = function () {
        return "Type - " + this.type + ", is alive - " + this.isAlive() + ", Have weapon - " + this.weapon +
            ", " + this.getFormattedHealth() + ', hero current damage - ' + this.getDamage() + ' points' +
            ", hero evasion - " + this.evasion;
    }
}
function Archer(maxHealth, basicDamage, evasion) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "archer";
}
var archer = new Archer(60, 5, 0.6);
archer.setWeapon(bow);
function Swordsman(maxHealth, basicDamage, evasion) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "swordsman";
}
var swordsman = new Swordsman(100, 10, 0.3);
swordsman.setWeapon(sword);

function Mage(maxHealth, basicDamage) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this.type = "mage";
    /*a method of treatment that works when the
     archer's health falls below his maximum health*/
    this.heal = function(target) {
        if (target.currentHeaalth < target.maxHealth) {
            target.currentHeaalth = Math.min(target.maxHealth,
                target.currentHeaalth + 50);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
var mage = new Mage(40, 15, 0.5);
// cycle until someone dies

while (archer.isAlive() && swordsman.isAlive()) {
    archer.kick(swordsman);
    mage.heal(archer);
    swordsman.kick(archer);
}
console.log(archer.toString());
console.log(swordsman.toString());
console.log(mage.toString());
```

Comment: т.к. приходящие параметры это строка и число (name, dmg), то такая проверка может быть странной. Я могу передать в name {} и оно без ошибок его в [object Object] превратит (toString). Для вашего случая надо чтобы параметры были тоже именоваными объектами, тогда их можно будет instanceOf отлавливать (https://learn.javascript.ru/instanceof)

Comment: Наверно проще сделать через typeof (https://learn.javascript.ru/types-introf)

Comment: У меня стоит задача в методах которые принимают параметры, гарантировать проверку на корректность параметра, через instanceof

Comment: ну просто (насколько мне известно) нельзя сделать вот так - `var n = 0; console.log( n instanceof Number)`. Поэтому и предположил что или делать параметры самостоятельными объектами с правилами (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals) или typeof или "превращать" их в объекты String и Number внутри методов и соотвтественно реагировать.

Comment: В чем проблема с проверкой, если ты уже делаешь ее `if (weapon instanceof !Weapon) {`, только почему-то внутр `catch` да еще и восклицательный знак зачем-то перед классом поставил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном коде идет неверное использование `instanceof`.

```
try {
    var me = this;
    me.weapon = weapon;
    return me;

} catch (e) {
    if (weapon instanceof !Weapon) {
        console.log(TypeError);
    }
}
```

---

Проверять типы нужно *вначале* функции. Это означает, что `if` нужно вынести из `catch`, и перенести в самый верх функции.

операндами `instanceof` являются объект слева и функция справа. В коде примера справа вместо функции используется выражение, которое возвращает `boolean`.

Чтобы проверить отрицание, его нужно применить ко всему выражению, а не к одному из операндов.

В итоге можно получить следующее:

```
this.setWeapon = function (weapon) {
    if (!(weapon instanceof Weapon)) { // проверяем тип
        throw new TypeError('weapon not Weapon') // кидаем ошибку
    }
    var me = this;
    me.weapon = weapon;
    return me;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Проблема в том, что литералы в JS ведут себя немного иначе чем объекты String или Number. [Тут описано что именно не так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203739/why-does-instanceof-return-false-for-some-literals). Я же предлагаю посмотреть как себя ведет JS при использовании instanceof. Я тут не описывал добавление exception потому что вопрос тут в поиске типа значения и способе отфильтровать неподходящие типы.

```js
var number = 0;
var num = new Number("200");
var notNumber = new Number("200j");
var string1 = "20open street";
var str = new String("20open street");
var notString = new String({});

console.log(number instanceof Number);
console.log(num instanceof Number);
console.log(notNumber instanceof Number);
console.log(string1 instanceof String);
console.log(str instanceof String);
console.log(notString instanceof String);

//но важно понимать, что значения внутри могут быть не числом (несмотря что instanceof is true)
console.log("---Not Number-----");
console.log(notNumber);
console.log(notNumber.toString());

//и не строкой (тут массив, который при toString выведет обычное [object Object]
console.log("---- Not String actually-----");
console.log(notString);
console.log(notString.toString());

//поэтому как альтернатива - использовать typeOf и сравнивать (ну и потом можно комбинировать с instance of если это все таки объект) 
// по ссылке пример -> typeof(s) === 'string' || s instanceof String;
console.log("---- Combine typeof and instanceOf-----");
console.log( typeof(number) === "number" || number instanceof Number);
console.log( typeof(string1) === "string" || string1 instanceof String);
```

Поэтому мое предположение состоит в том, что чисто через instanceof проверку провести нельзя - нужно сочетание подходов.